# Combining flash swf files into one

Tags: flash

I have tried on google with no luck so before I spend anymore time on this would like to know if it's possible.

I have 50ish very small 1 - 2 second swf files each one is like one slide.  I would like to combine them all together into one flash file.

Is this possible, as a note I don't have the original source files I have just been provided with the swf files.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case if your swf files were published **without** option `Protect from import`, you can simply create a new flash project and import there all your 50 swf files the same way you import any other media file(), and later play on a timeline with a correct position/time for every of them.

To test if you were lucky to have non-protected swf files, simply create a new flash project in the Flash and use `Import > Import to Library` one of your swf files and see if you have an error message.

Comment: for some reason, this seems to crash Flash CS6 almost every time I try to import..is there any other settings when publishing that make importing easier/faster?  Like unchecking creating the associated HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AS3 Loader . See documentation at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flex SDK, you could use `[Embed(source="file.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]` meta to embed SWFs as plain data. Later you could use `Loader.loadBytes(swfByteArray);` to "create" them. This, however, will not work on iOS because the bytecode generated for Flash on iOS is different.